# R Statistics: Average True Range Trailing Stop indicator

Tags: r, statistics, indicator, quantmod

I am using the following article:

[marintrading.com/106VERV.PDF](http://marintrading.com/106VERV.PDF)

to create the Average True Range Trailing Stop indicator in R.  I have tried various ways to do this, including for loops, pmin and creating a lagging time series, and nothing seems to work.

Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you trying to create it?  It's available in the [TTR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/index.html) in the function `ATR`.

UPDATE (after reading the question more closely).  I'm not exactly sure this is the solution, but I hope it helps you in the right direction.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AMD", from="2005-11-01", to="2006-08-01")
AMD$stopLongATR <- -3.5*ATR(HLC(AMD),5)[,"atr"]
AMD$stopShortATR <- 3.5*ATR(HLC(AMD),5)[,"atr"]

chartSeries(AMD, TA=NULL)
addTA(runMax(Cl(AMD)+AMD$stopLongATR,10), on=1)
addTA(runMin(Cl(AMD)+AMD$stopShortATR,10), on=1)
```

UPDATE #2:

I missed the trailing stop logic in the article.  This code replicates it more closely.  Note that the `coredata` calls are necessary because `trail` is path-dependent and we need to compare yesterday's values with today's.  xts/zoo operations merge by index before the operation, so we need to drop the index before comparing.

```
AMD$trail <- 0
AMD$AMD.lagCl <- lag(Cl(AMD))

for(i in 6:NROW(AMD)) {
  trail1 <- coredata(AMD$trail[i-1])

  if(Cl(AMD)[i] > trail1 && AMD$AMD.lagCl[i] > trail1) {
    AMD$trail[i] <- max(trail1,coredata(Cl(AMD)[i]+AMD$stopLongATR[i]))
  } else
  if(Cl(AMD)[i] < trail1 && AMD$AMD.lagCl[i] < trail1) {
    AMD$trail[i] <- min(trail1,coredata(Cl(AMD)[i]+AMD$stopShortATR[i]))
  } else
  if(Cl(AMD)[i] > trail1) {
    AMD$trail[i] <- coredata(Cl(AMD)[i]+AMD$stopLongATR[i])
  } else {
    AMD$trail[i] <- coredata(Cl(AMD)[i]+AMD$stopShortATR[i])
  }
}

chartSeries(AMD)
addTA(AMD$trail, on=1)
```

Comment: Hi, I am using the ATR function in the TTR package, but the code I'm trying to write is a trailing stop using the ATR, where I'm having challenges.

Comment: @Jessica: my apologies, I didn't read your question carefully enough.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Awesome thank you that helps!  What is the best way to get the indicator to switch from below to above after the price trend breaks below stopShortATR?  I was thinking to use a for loop but might be a bit slow?

Comment: @Jessica: I misread the article.  Please see my corrected answer.  A loop is probably easiest because trail depends on previous values of itself.